# Cypress- How can we list key names under certain key (not values of these keys)

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I want to store key names under a certain key. Here is an example:

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    }
}}
```

There is no problem to reach end values like "sun1". I want to reach the key names under "image" as "src", "name" ...; and store them as an array. I don't need their values. How can I do that? I'm parsing response in "then" structure; so this type of answer would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), which will return an array containing the keys in that object.

```
const myObj = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false,
  baz: 'string'
}

cy.then(() => {
  const keys = Object.keys(myObj);
  console.log(keys) // ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
});
```

If you needed both keys and values, you can use [Object.entries().](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 5):

The image tag is deeply nested in the outer object.

This is how I would approach it

```js
cy.request(...)
  .then(data => {
    const imageKeys = Cypress._.keys(data.widget.image)
    expect(imageKeys).to.deep.eq(['src', 'name', 'hOffset', 'vOffset', 'alignment'])
  })
```

You can also chain commands,

```js
cy.request(...)
  .its('widget.image')
  .then(Cypress._.keys)
  .should(imageKeys => {
    expect(imageKeys).to.deep.eq(['src', 'name', 'hOffset', 'vOffset', 'alignment'])
  })
```